# IDE for R in OSX?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, development, r

I am trying to find some editor/IDE for R in OSX. 
I am using currently TextMate but not probably the good choice.

How can you type R in some good editor/IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily install `rstudio` by typing the following:

```
brew cask install rstudio
```

To be able to install it, you need [homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed and [homebrew cask](http://caskroom.io).

To install `homebrew` type:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

To enable `homebrew cask` type:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

Comment: There's also a [RStudio disk image installer](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/)